# List server folders and files as tree with Folder View (PHP)

Tags: php, css

How can I display the files and sub folders on the server in Folder View? (PHP)

Example -

[image: http://www.dmxzone.com/downloads/images/FV_FilesTree.jpg]

I used the following code to generate the listed folders and subfolders -

```
<?php
function listFolderFiles($dir)
{
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff)
    {
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')
        {
            echo '<li style="list-style-type:square">'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) 
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
listFolderFiles('C:\wamp\www');
?>
```

Just want to know **two things** -

1. How to have that plus-minus (expand-hide) feature on the folders?
2. How to directly open any specific file by clicking it? It should
       open in read only mode in the default software set for that particular file extension
       in the client machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. use JavaScript 2. this is almost impossible to do these days due to security restrictions in browsers.

Comment: @Pekka>> Thanks for the reply. How to use JavaScript2 for 1. ? Can you please elaborate.